# Check TXT file for coincidences

Tags: php, regex

I have a txt file called `blacklist.txt`. I need to check if the entered `$fullURL` or any of its subdomains are in the file and if it not, do some functions. I already did this code but it always echoes `$bannedmsg`, what am I doing wrong?

```
$blacklist = file("./blacklist.txt"); 
$words = "/.*";
foreach ($blacklist as $zeile){
    if ($zeile == $blacklist[count($blacklist)-1]){
        $words .= trim($zeile);
    }else{
        $words .= trim($zeile);
        $words .= "|";
    }
}  
$words .= ".*/";
preg_match($words, $fullURL, $results);
if(empty($results)){ 
    // Do the function
}else{
    //This is banned, echo $bannedmsg and die()
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that `blacklist.txt` doesn't contain any blank lines? Have you tried printing out `$words` to make sure it looks right? (By the way, I think you should remove the `.*` at the beginning and end of `$words`; it's unnecessary and misleading.)

Comment: And for that matter -- it doesn't really make sense to build this big `$words` regex. Your `foreach ($blacklist as $zeile)`-loop should just perform the comparison you need, echoing `$bannedmsg` and dying if it detects a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you are generating the wrong regular expression.  The best thing to do in situations like this is to open up your program a bit and look at the inputs and outputs at each step.  For instance, if that foreach loop does not execute (why would that happen?), your regular expression will end up looking like this:

```
/.*.*/
```

That regex will match any input.  Even if the file is found, though, you're probably still not getting what you really want.  In this case your regex probably ends up looking something like:

```
/.*url1.com|url2.com|url3.com.*/
```

That's not the alternation you're looking for.  It will match all of the following:

1. url1.com
2. whitelistedurl1.com
3. url1-command
4. url3.com.google.com

It will *not* match *subdomain.url2.com*.  A strict set of [unit tests](http://www.simpletest.org/) would be really helpful for a program like this one.

Ultimately, you probably want parans to dictate where your alternation starts and stops (to solve the url2.com problem), to escape your blacklist content with regard to regexes (to rule out (3)), a check for the end of the string (to rule out (4)), and an optional dot at the beginning (to rule out (2)).  Something like this:

```
/.*\.?(url1\.com|url2\.com|url3\.com)$/
```

This is just a guess, though, without knowing the formats you're dealing with.  The best route, again, is thorough testing of each component and at least rudimentary error checking.